# Finding elements in XML file

Tags: python, xml

I have the following XML file:

```html
<annotation>
  <folder>KAIST Multispectral Ped Benchmark</folder>
  <filename>set00/V003/I00397</filename>
  <source>
    <database>KAIST pedestrian</database>
    <annotation>KAIST pedestrian</annotation>
    <image>KAIST pedestrian</image>
    <url>https://soonminhwang.github.io/rgbt-ped-detection/</url>
    <note>Sanitized training annotation [BMVC18] (https://li-chengyang.github.io/home/MSDS-RCNN/)</note>
  </source>
  <size>
    <width>640</width>
    <height>512</height>
    <depth>4</depth>
  </size>
  <segmented>0</segmented>
  <object>
    <name>person</name>
    <bndbox>
      <x>457</x>
      <y>217</y>
      <w>31</w>
      <h>78</h>
    </bndbox>
    <pose>unknown</pose>
    <truncated>0</truncated>
    <difficult>0</difficult>
    <occlusion>0</occlusion>
  </object>
  <object>
    <name>person</name>
    <bndbox>
      <x>486</x>
      <y>217</y>
      <w>29</w>
      <h>78</h>
    </bndbox>
    <pose>unknown</pose>
    <truncated>0</truncated>
    <difficult>0</difficult>
    <occlusion>0</occlusion>
  </object>
  <object>
    <name>people</name>
    <bndbox>
      <x>420</x>
      <y>226</y>
      <w>26</w>
      <h>41</h>
    </bndbox>
    <pose>unknown</pose>
    <truncated>0</truncated>
    <difficult>0</difficult>
    <occlusion>0</occlusion>
  </object>
</annotation>
```

I want to extract certain elements from the file. For example, under object, there are three names 'person', 'person' and 'people'. I have using the following method to extract the 'bndbox' values:

```
box = {e.tag: int(e.text) for e in root.findall('.//bndbox/*')}
```

which outputs:

```
{'x': 420, 'y': 226, 'w': 26, 'h': 41}
```

But when i use the same method for finding 'name', i get the following output:

```
label = {e.tag: e.text for e in root.findall('.//name')}
{'name': 'people'}
```

This seems to be only outputting the final value.

Any advise would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: have a look here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.html

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
[name.text for name in root.findall('object/name')]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This works perfectly. However, when I use it for the bndbox, I get a list of all the 'x', 'y', 'w', and 'h' values like so: ['449', '220', '28', '69', '474', '220', '27', '70', '421', '228', '23', '38']. Is there any way that I can have lists for each set of x, y, w, h values like this: [['449', '220', '28', '69'], ['474', '220', '27', '70'], ['421', '228', '23', '38']]?

Answer (score 0):

Here (working code based on etree)

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '''<annotation>
  <folder>KAIST Multispectral Ped Benchmark</folder>
  <filename>set00/V003/I00397</filename>
  <source>
    <database>KAIST pedestrian</database>
    <annotation>KAIST pedestrian</annotation>
    <image>KAIST pedestrian</image>
    <url>https://soonminhwang.github.io/rgbt-ped-detection/</url>
    <note>Sanitized training annotation [BMVC18] (https://li-chengyang.github.io/home/MSDS-RCNN/)</note>
  </source>
  <size>
    <width>640</width>
    <height>512</height>
    <depth>4</depth>
  </size>
  <segmented>0</segmented>
  <object>
    <name>person</name>
    <bndbox>
      <x>457</x>
      <y>217</y>
      <w>31</w>
      <h>78</h>
    </bndbox>
    <pose>unknown</pose>
    <truncated>0</truncated>
    <difficult>0</difficult>
    <occlusion>0</occlusion>
  </object>
  <object>
    <name>person</name>
    <bndbox>
      <x>486</x>
      <y>217</y>
      <w>29</w>
      <h>78</h>
    </bndbox>
    <pose>unknown</pose>
    <truncated>0</truncated>
    <difficult>0</difficult>
    <occlusion>0</occlusion>
  </object>
  <object>
    <name>people</name>
    <bndbox>
      <x>420</x>
      <y>226</y>
      <w>26</w>
      <h>41</h>
    </bndbox>
    <pose>unknown</pose>
    <truncated>0</truncated>
    <difficult>0</difficult>
    <occlusion>0</occlusion>
  </object>
</annotation>'''

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
names = [n.text for n in root.findall('.//object/name')]
print(names)
boxes = [[box.find('x').text, box.find('y').text, box.find('w').text, 
          box.find('h').text] for box in
          root.findall('.//object/bndbox')]
print(boxes)
```

output

```
['person', 'person', 'people']
[['457', '217', '31', '78'], ['486', '217', '29', '78'], ['420', '226', '26', '41']]
```

Comment: Thank you, this method also works. Would you have any advice for my question in the reply to the above comment?

Comment: S.Ahmed - Code was added to support your comment

Comment: Glad to help. If the code works for you feel free to vote up.